# Get field values from mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to get the individual field values from a mysql table. I am using a mysql stored procedure (get_data) and a python cursor and I can get the entire record, but I cannot figure out how to get the individual fields so that I can place them into variables.

for example, in the following I want to place Smith into the variable last_name, John into first_name, etc.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc('get_data', [9, ])
for result in cursor.stored_results():
print(result.fetchone()
```

Results:

```
(9, 'Smith', 'John', '', '(903) 777-5555. Box 99', 'Somewhere', 'TX', 75999 )
```

Answer (score 0):

put the fetchone result into a variable
and use index to get the value

example

```
aaa = result.fetchone()
print(aaa[0]) # 9
print(aaa[1]) # Smith

last_name = aaa[1]
first_name = aaa[2]

print(last_name, first_name) # Smith John
```

reply to comment

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc('get_data', [9, ])
for result in cursor.stored_results():
    print(result.fetchone()) # (9, 'Smith', 'John', '', '(903) 777-5555. Box 99', 'Somewhere', 'TX', 75999 )
    no_id = result.fetchone()[0] # 9
    last_name = result.fetchone()[1] # SMith
    first_name = result.fetchone()[2] # John
    print(f"FirstName: {first_name} | LastName: {last_name}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I am getting-
NameError: name 'result' is not defined

Comment: need to define the 'result' variable as you have in your loop. just your use original code and replace the print(result.fetchone()) with print(result.fetchone()[0]) or print(result.fetchone()[1]) or print(result.fetchone()[2])

Comment: I am getting the error in the line:
aaa = results.fetchone()
So somehow I am not getting the fetchone() into the variable. the compiler is not recognizing results

Answer (score 0):

`result.fetchone()` returns tuple you can get each of fields by using its index

```
row = result.fetchone()

row[0] #9
row[4] #(903) 652-2038
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was making it much more complicated than it really is.

Comment: Again thanks for the input. My problem now is if send non existing ID which of course returns nothing the code crashes when I try
 row = result.fetchone()

Comment: different question/scope, research it out if you don't find answer post it up as question with details, asking follow up questions in comments is not allowed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321819/can-comment-contain-a-question, also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers